# Power Law in Excel works better than R?

Tags: r, modeling

I am trying to model some data.  I am having better luck with Excel than R, but the Excel solution won't scale so I need to figure how to do this in R.

Excel will map a trendline to the data and a Power curve yields a reasonable y = 0.6462x^-0.542.

When I put the same data into R and try to model it with the continuous power-law in the `poweRlaw` package I get something like `y = 0.14901x^-3.03671`.  The intercept is way too small and the alpha is way too big.

```
# 14 days of % of users retained
y = c(0.61431   , 0.42585   , 0.35427   , 0.33893   , 0.28853   , 0.26004   , 0.2352    , 0.20087   , 0.17969   , 0.1848    , 0.17311   , 0.17092   , 0.15777   , 0.14901)

y.pl = conpl$new(y)
y.pl_est = estimate_xmin(c_pl)
y.pl_est

# $KS
# 0.1068587
#
# $xmin
# 0.14901
#
# $pars
# 3.03673
#
# $ntail
# 14
```

[image: Image shows how the models built from 14-days of data with Excel and R conpl() match up to the Actuals out to day 60]

Is there a way to use `lm` or `glm` to do a power curve that give reasonable intercept and alpha?

Comment: As note on the `poweRlaw` attempt, [looking at its vignette](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/poweRlaw/vignettes/a_introduction.pdf) it seems like it is made to estimate *power law probability distributions*, which is not what you are doing. Probability distributions, for example, must have the area under the curve sum to 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't used the `poweRlaw` package, but R's base `nls` (non-linear least squares) function gives results similar to what you got with Excel. If there were a difference, after checking my code for errors, my first thought would be "so much the worse for Excel" :).

```
# Data
dat = data.frame(x=1:14,
y = c(0.61431   , 0.42585   , 0.35427   , 0.33893   , 0.28853   , 0.26004   , 0.2352    , 0.20087   , 0.17969   , 0.1848    , 0.17311   , 0.17092   , 0.15777   , 0.14901))

# Model
m1 = nls(y ~ a*x^b, list(a=1,b=1), data=dat)
summary(m1)

Formula: y ~ a * x^b

Parameters:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
  a  0.62104    0.01307   47.51 4.94e-15 ***
  b -0.51460    0.01525  -33.74 2.92e-13 ***

# Plot nls model
curve(coef(m1)[1]*x^coef(m1)[2], from=1, to=14)

# Add curve for Excel model in red
curve(0.6462*x^(-0.542), from=1, to=14, col="red", lty=2, add=TRUE)

# Add data points
points(dat$x, dat$y)
```

[image]

Comment: WOOT!!!  WOOT!!!  Excellent answer...totally changed my approach is giving me much more reasonable projections.  Sincerely appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 8):

Seems like Excel might be doing a linear model with normal errors on a log scale - I match the Excel results to as many decimal places as you share when I take logs of `x` and `y` before modeling.

Using @eipi10's nicely shared data frame:

```
dat = transform(dat, logx = log(x), logy = log(y))
mod = lm(logy ~ logx, data = dat)

## intercept
exp(coef(mod)[1])
# (Intercept) 
#   0.6461621 

## power
coef(mod)[2]
#       logx 
# -0.5424412
```

This works, of course because if

```
      y = a * x ^ b
 log(y) = log(a) + b * log(x)
```

So the fitted coefficients of the linear model are `log(a)` and `b` in the power model.

The difference is the assumption of the error distribution. The other answer using NLS minimizes squared error on the power scale - which is the MLE if you assume normally distributed errors in `y`. This method (so apparently Excel's method as well) assumes that errors are normal on the log scale, which means assuming log-normal errors on the untransformed scale - which may very well be more appropriate. (Though from the graph in eipi's answer we can see the differences in fitted values are very small.)

Comment: Nice explanation Gregor.

Comment: Gregor - the explanation you provide was very beneficial in helping me digest eipi10's answer.  Really appreciate you taking the time to lay this out.